# NotSerializableException occuring where it shouldn't

Tags: java, notserializableexception

I've been working with Java for a few months now and I'm still fairly new to it, so any help is appreciated. I've been working on a game for a while now (based off another game) and wanted to make a level editor. I'm having trouble saving the information to a .ser file, even though I do it other places in other classes with no problem. The error is `java.io.NotSerializableException: resources.Sample$Ball`, but the line number it is giving me has nothing to do with that class. I have a class called Sample, and inside that there is a private class called Ball so I understand that much, but the fact that it is giving me information for it makes no sense. The `Sample` class is ever only used once in a single class, and it's not the one I get the error in. I've never had issues with this class or the `Ball` subclass because they're very secluded and rarely ever used.

The two line numbers the error gives me are:

`at LevelEditor.saveDialog(LevelEditor.java:309)
at LevelEditor.actionPerformed(LevelEditor.java:256)`

The lines of code at those line numbers are as followed:

`oos.writeObject(new CustomSave(platforms, stars, ball, levelSize));`

Which is where the problem is actually occuring, and the other line number is just where I call the function that the above code lies in. The variables that the `CustomSave` class takes in still have nothing to do with the `Sample` or `Ball` classes. And because the `CustomSave` class is so small I will provide that here as well. I will also provide context to the line number above.

**Context to Code**

```
try {
    File f = new File(filename);
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(new CustomSave(platforms, stars, ball, levelSize));
    oos.close();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**CustomSave Class**

```
package resources;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import resources.BouncyBall;

public class CustomSave implements Serializable {
    private ArrayList<DragablePlatform> platforms;
    private ArrayList<StarPolygon> stars;

    private StaticBall ball;
    private Dimension levelSize;

    public CustomSave(ArrayList<DragablePlatform> platforms, ArrayList<StarPolygon> stars, StaticBall ball, Dimension levelSize){
        this.platforms = platforms; this.stars = stars; this.ball = ball; this.levelSize = levelSize;
    }

    public ArrayList<DragablePlatform> getPlatforms() {
        return platforms;
    }
    public ArrayList<StarPolygon> getStars() {
        return stars;
    }
    public BouncyBall getBall() {
        return ball;
    }
    public Dimension getLevelSize() {
        return levelSize;
    }
}
```

Again I don't know why I'm getting this error, because it makes no sense. To try troubleshooting I tried implementing `Serializable` on the `Ball` class within the `Sample` class and that fixed the problem to an extent. The error stopped listing `Sample$Ball` as the problem, but instead listed another random class as the problem, another class that has absolutely nothing with what I'm trying to do.

**Full Error**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: resources.Sample$Ball
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at LevelEditor.saveDialog(LevelEditor.java:454)
at LevelEditor.actionPerformed(LevelEditor.java:298)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Level Editor Line 454**

`oos.writeObject(new CustomSave(platforms, stars, ball, levelSize));`

**Level Editor Line 298**

`saveDialog();` (The function that contains the above line)

All help is greatly appreciated, and if you need anything else just ask.

Thank you.

Comment: `f.createNewFile();` is pointless here. `new FileOutputStream()` already does it, so you're forcing it to delete the file you just created and create another one. Somewhere you have a reference to this `Ball` class that is being serialized. The stack trace comes from the `writeObject()` call, not the non-serializable class it found.

Comment: You will get this error if `StaticBall` or `Dimension` is not serializable, or if either of those classes contains references to non-serializable classes. Since you haven't shown the code we cannot really help.  You must follow ALL the reference chains from the main object being serialized.  If you would provide the necessary details such as the error messages and complete stack trace along with all the pertinent code it might help.

Comment: @JimGarrison `Static Ball` is serializable, the class it extends however is not. Because when I do make that class serializable I get the error above (I posted the full error now). I 'fixed' this by removing the `implements Serializable` from the extended class, but I'm now at a point where I need that class to be Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

to Serialization properly you have to make sure all the classes you are going to serialize implement the Serializable interface, I had the same problem once I tried to save one object at a time and see what object caused the problem
 - flush the oos.

```
try {        
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(platforms);
    oos.writeObject(stars);
    oos.writeObject(balls);
    oos.writeObject(levelSize);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
}catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `flush()` is redundant before `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

For serialization / deserialization to be successful, the following two conditions must be true:

1. The class you want to serialize / deserialize must implement the
   [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)
   interface.
2. All fields in that class must either be primitive types or must implement the
   [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable) interface.

Condition 1 (Satisfied): since
`CustomSave implements Serializable`

Condition 2 (?): Do `StaticBall`, `DragablePlatform` and `StarPolygon` implement Serializable?

```
private ArrayList<DragablePlatform> platforms; // ArrayList implements Serializable? Yes, DragablePlatform implements Serializable?
private ArrayList<StarPolygon> stars; // ArrayList implements Serializable? Yes, StartPolygon implements Serializable?
private StaticBall ball; // StaticBall implements Serializable?
private Dimension levelSize; // Dimension implements Serializable? Yes
```

Comment: As you said, condition 1 is met, and I checked all of the other class and I had them all implement  Serializable. And even if one of them didn't I don't understand why it's giving me the `Ball` class within `Sample` as the error. And as for the answer above you, I did them all independently and the error I'm getting is with StaticBall.

Comment: It appears I just accidentally fixed it. The class `StaticBall` was extending another class. That class was also implementing Serializable. When I noticed this I got rid of that out of curiosity and it fixed it. Why would this have been the problem, and why would it start identifying other random classes as the problem when they in fact had nothing to do with the problem and had no direct relationship with the class that was the problem? Regardless though, thanks for your help.